# Silverlight OOB Error? File Dialog Box popup? Parallels? Oye?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, parallels

[image]

Recently I updated Parallels, and found myself in a bit of a predicament.

Now when I build/run the app, I get a save, open file dialog box for an html file.  Behind the dialog box, is whats present in the embedded image.  That's a borderless OOBE app.

The weird thing is, if I open the html file, it keeps that blank page but displays the out of browser content in the browser.  The app is even detecting that it's out of the browser, when its really in the browser.

What I do know, is it's localized to the machine, and not the app itself.  I've pulled a new clone from the mercurial repo, rerun it, same problem, moved it to another machine, and it has no problem.  Displays fine.

I've even set IE as my default browser, I just wonder if Parallels is doing something funky.  Attempting to repair my install of Visual Studio but I expect that will not fix the problem.  Reinstalled an older version of parallels.  No change.  Even removed parallels tools, nothing.

It's really weird.  Any suggestions on what to do?  Right now I'm at my wits end.

Comment: The problem ended up being Parallels, or Parallels tools, even reinstalled both parallels and the VM.  Hopefully not a lot of people run into this, or they fix the problem right away.  Up until now I had really liked parallels.

Comment: Parallels bug fix in, everything looks good now.

Answer (score 0):

Check your project properties

Also if your project is hosted in an asp.net project, make sure it is "Set as StartUp Project"

Have you tried to publish your app in IIS?  Is it working?

Comment: Right but this is localized to a machine.  Not the code.  I've downloaded the Mercurial Repo fresh, on the same machine, and another.  My machine, doesn't work, the other machine does work.  Same code, same settings.

Comment: When you run your project using an embedded ASP.NET project, it runs it with "ASP.NET Development Server" using a port specified in the project properties.  Maybe your computer has a problem using that port, try another one maybe...

Comment: But why would it serve up the file, with a save or open dialog box, if the port was blocked?  Also how would I change the port for the server?  Be nice to know either way :)

Comment: Well, I don't know it was just a guess.  To change the port go to your Web Application project properties under the "Web" tab you have a radio-button "Use Visual Studio Development Server" there you can set a specific port.

Comment: Anything is worth a try:)  Thanks for the reply either way. I think I'm close to a format.  I've lost to much productivity as is.  My guess is, there is a parallels App associated with .htm  deciding which browser to open, and its interfering with it.  It was fine before though.

Comment: Weird,... let us know if you find something and if formatting solved the issue.  Good luck :)

Comment: Reinstalled Windows 7 with the current version of Parallels.  And I immediately upon starting the install of visual studio I had a similar problem.  Dialog box, so I backed out, and started using my old VMware Fusion that hadn't touched in about a year. Reinstalled, and everything is now great.  That was a pain.